# How Can I open another App from my app?

Tags: iphone, sdk

I have rediATM app installed on my iphone. rediATM app is free on itunes.
I want to open that app from my iphone app.
I am not able to find out the way to open it.

i am using the following code to open it but it takes me to the website.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/au/app/rediatm-finder/id358936470?mt=8"]];
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

It does not work because you are opening the **download link** for itunes.

If you want to open another app on your iPhone with your own app, you must find out if this app provides a **custom URL scheme**. If they do, you could open the app using that custom URL, but otherwise not.

Here is an example how to create a custom URL scheme for your own app [Launching Your iPhone App Via Custom URL Scheme](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html) and Apple's documentation: [Communicating with Other Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW18)

Comment: How can I find out whether that(rediATM) application has the custom URL scheme enabled or not?

Comment: It says that the app is copyrighted by eHound Pty Ltd. So find out their website and contact them. They should know..